# css - reset hover selector on click

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, css-transitions

I have this class the response of displaying tooltip after 1.5s hover.

```
&:hover .tooltip {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transform: translateY(0);
    transition-delay: 1.5s;
}
```

I'm using this class on a button.
I would like that when user clicking on this button, the transition-delay will start count from the beginning - means the tooltip will be displayed only after 1.5s again.

what't the best approach doing it?

Comment: If I understand your question you want the timer to reset whenever you click the element, right? If that is the case I would suggest you to use JavaScript for that, at least that's the way i do it and it works all the time with no issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:active` pseudo-class too:

```
&:hover .tooltip,
&:active .tooltip {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transform: translateY(0);
    transition-delay: 1.5s;
}
```